# Problems With Outlook Automatically Closing From Access Database

Tags: vba, outlook

I was just upgraded to windows 10.  This version of outlook I have enabled the macros in the trust center however it limits me on running vba from outlook.  Also access is having issues when I run the task scheduler and run from a bat file the access database.  An autoexec excutes and I tell the system to shut outlook down but it won't shut down the current instance of the outlook.  Here Is the code I am using.

```
Public Function OutlookClose1()
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Outlook.exe'")
For Each objProcess In colProcessList
Set objOutlook = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.application")
objOutlook.Quit
Next

End Function
Public Function OutlookClose2()
Dim objAppOL As Outlook.Application
On Error Resume Next
Set objAppOL = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.application")
    objAppOL.Quit
Set objAppOL = Nothing
Exit Function
End Function
```

I have tried outlookclose1 and 2 and neither work.  DOes anyone have suggestions?

Also when running the outlookclose1 from the vba editor it does close.  It takes the exchange offline, which I don't want.  But from a bat file running the access database and having the autoexec run it it doesn't close down outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler runs as a service in a security context different  from the currently logged in user even if the local user account is the same. COM system refuses to marshal calls between processes running in different security contexts.

Comment: What can I do in Dcom to fix this or what can I do to fix this or what do I need to tell the domain admin?  There must be a domain or gpedit fix is there not?

Comment: There is not much you can do - Outlook (like any other Office app) cannot be used from a service such as the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I have office 2013 and windows 10.  I could use the above code with Windows 7 and the task scheduler.  I am on a domain with certain policies that I can't change and I don't have admin rights.  At home not on a domain I can use that code too.  With that being said I can at least terminate outlook from access and get the job done closing an outlook session so when the autoexec runs in the access database it closes outlook and then runs the reports and sends, Create Object Outlook.Application and it sends emails no problems.  Here is how I terminate the code.  The reason is I don't want multiple outlook sessions running.

```
Public Function OutlookClose1()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application

delay = 30000 'delay in milliseconds to let Outlook close gracefully
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Outlook.exe'")
For Each objProcess In colProcessList
objProcess.Terminate
Next
Set objWMIService = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set colProcessList = Nothing
End Function
```